# Slide out menu in Angular

Tags: angular

I would like to design a method to slide submenus when clicking on an item from the main menu of my Angular application.

So if I click on `Accueil`, the `Home` element should appear instead of the `Accueil` element.

**online.ts**

```
export class OnlineComponent implements OnInit {
  nav: IMenuItem[] = [];

  constructor(private onlineService: OnlineService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Initialize the 'nav' property with data from the 'onlineService'
    this.nav = this.onlineService.IMenuItem;
  }

  toggleSubMenu(index: number) {
    // Toggle the active state of the clicked item
    this.nav[index].active = !this.nav[index].active;

    // Ensure that all other items are deactivated
    for (let i = 0; i < this.nav.length; i++) {
      if (i !== index) {
        this.nav[i].active = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**online.html**

```
<div class="container text-center" *ngIf="nav">
    <div class="sideBar">
      <div class="menu-content">
        <ul class="menu-items">
          <li class="item" *ngFor="let menuItem of nav; let i = index">
            <div class="menu-item" (click)="toggleSubMenu(i)">
              <!-- Display the menu item name -->
              <span class="title">{{ menuItem.name }}</span>
            </div>
            <ul class="submenu" *ngIf="menuItem.active">
              <li class="subitem" *ngFor="let subItem of menuItem.sub">
                <div class="submenu-item">
                  <!-- Add [routerLink] directive to manage navigation -->
                  <a [routerLink]="subItem.state">{{ subItem.name }}</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
    <!-- This is where the routed components will be displayed -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

For your information, my code is available on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ekafl2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fviews%2Fonline%2Fonline.component.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would use Angular's built-in animations

```
// app.module.ts

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // other imports ...
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  // ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

component

```
// online.component.ts

import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  // ... other properties ...
  animations: [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
      state('in', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
      transition('void => *', [
        style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }),
        animate(300)
      ]),
      transition('* => void', [
        animate(300, style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class OnlineComponent {
  // ... rest of the component ...
}
```

your manu

```
 <!-- online.html -->

<li class="item" *ngFor="let menuItem of nav; let i = index">
  <div class="menu-item" (click)="toggleSubMenu(i)">
    <span class="title">{{ menuItem.name }}</span>
  </div>
  <ul class="submenu" *ngIf="menuItem.active" [@slideInOut]="'in'">
    <li class="subitem" *ngFor="let subItem of menuItem.sub">
      <div class="submenu-item">
        <a [routerLink]="subItem.state">{{ subItem.name }}</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```